# Php not setting cookie

Tags: php, cookies, bluehost

```
?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Login extends Controller

{

function index()

{

    $data['main'] ='';

    $data['error'] = '';

    if($this->input->post('username'))

    {

        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $config = $this->maincore->get_config();

        if($username == $config['admin_username'] && md5($password) == $config['admin_password']){

        $value = $username.".".md5($password);



        $time = 9000;

        if($this->input->post('remember')) { 

        $time =  time()+3600*24*5;  

        }

    setcookie("feeder_login", $value, $time, '/');

    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$this->config->site_url().'">';

    exit;
```

I cleared my cookies in chrome and firefox. After my script running. No new cookies are at at all.

I know the script is working as it redirects me to the main page after running.

Comment: You say you know its working, but its not working? I'm confused. If you echo $_COOKIE['feeder_login'] is it there? It might not be there on initial page load - you may have to wait for a refresh.

Comment: are `$value`and `$time`correct?

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to see if the cookie is being set?

Comment: Are you sure the expiration time is in the future? It should be a unix timestamp. If it's not in the future, I think it will unset (or never set) the cookie.

Comment: What are `value` and `time`?  `value` needs to be truthy or `'0'`, and `time` needs to be in the future.

Comment: I added the rest of the code to the post. Value is a username/password combo, and time is 9000, or more.

Comment: I know the script is working. It goes through all of the code, and redirects the page on the line right after the cookie is set. If I enter the wrong username or password, it does not redirect me. It never sets a cookie. I tried firebug, and no cookies are set. I cleared cookies in chrome and firefox and looked at them after I run the script, they both show up with 0 cookies set.

Answer (score 0):

When setting cookies you can not output anything before that. I am pretty sure you've outputting something with `"echo()"` before `setcookie()`.
If you have an empty character before your

```
<?php
setcookie("test", "this is a cookie");
?>
```

and it should really work.

Comment: Using that script does work. I've updated my question with the full source. NOTHING is being printed before the set cookie command, or echoed, or anything. Why will this script not work?

Comment: @user1189764, it looks like you are using codeigniter then why you are not using ci's session class and also using meta redirect instead of ci's url class' redirect.  I think you should utilize ci's power and let all the things (cookie) done by CI.

Comment: I don't want to use CI's session. I want to use my own cookie system?